# How can I get the determinant of an 8x8 matrix in a particular form?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

I would like to get the determinant of a 8x8 matrix with symbolic representation to a particular form. When I used determinant and fullsimply to answer was too long and did not match the form I was looking for.

My matrix is:

```
{{1,1,0,0, -E^(-I k d),-E^(I k' d),0,0},{E^(I γ),-E^(-I γ),0,0,-E^(I (θ- k d)),E^(-I (θ- k d)),0,0},{E^(-I(ϕ1-β)), E^(-I(ϕ1+β)),0,0,0,0, -E^(-I k' d),-E^(I k' d)},{E^(I (γ-ϕ1+β)),E^(-I (γ+ϕ1+β)), 0,0,0,0,-E^(-I (θ' +k' d)),E^(I (θ' +k' d))},{0,0,1,1,-1,-1,0,0},{0,0,E^(I γ),-E^(-I γ),-E^(I θ),E^(-I θ),0,0},{0,0,E^(-I (ϕ2+β)),E^(-I (ϕ2-β)),0,0,-1,-1},{0,0,E^(-I (γ-ϕ2-β)),-E^(-I (γ+ϕ2-β)),0,0,-E^(-I θ'),E^(I θ')}}
```

I need to get the determinant of the form $A'\sin(2β) + B'\cos(2β) + C' = 0$ where $A'$,$B'$ and $C'$ are of the form

$$A' = \cos(k'd) \cos(γ) \cos(θ') \sin(kd)(\sin γ\sinθ−1)+\cos(kd) \cos(γ) \cos(θ) \sin(k'd)+12\cos(kd) \cos(θ) \sin(2γ) \sin(k'd)$$
$$B' = \sin(k'd) \sin(kd)(\sin θ \sin γ + \sin θ \sin θ'\sin^2γ − \sin θ'\sin γ − 1)$$
$$C' = \cos^2(γ) \cos(θ) \cos(θ') \cos(ϕ) − \sin(kd) \sin(k'd)(\sin θ \sin θ' − \sin^2γ + \sin γ(\sin θ − \sin θ'))$$

or something similar.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or give me an idea on how to do this because I am quite new to Mathematica and do not know how to proceed with this.

Comment: Look at `kb' // FullForm` I am guessing that is not what you intend. Start by using proper variable names.

Comment: That is my bad, I had picked up the expression from a different source and it had totally slipped my mind. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. This answer is a bit tedious, but it works.

Change the exponentials to trigs:

```
te = TrigExpand[ExpToTrig[Det[mat]]]
(*long expression*)
```

Find the coefficients of your trig terms:

```
cb2 =    Coefficient[te, Cos[β]^2]
cs2 =    Coefficient[te, Sin[β]^2]
cscb =   Coefficient[te, Sin[β] Cos[β]]
cPrime = Select[te, FreeQ[#, β] &, Infinity]
```

Check:

```
Simplify[te == (cb2 Cos[β]^2 + cs2 Sin[β]^2 + cscb Sin[β] Cos[β] + cPrime)]
(*True*)
```

Create a symbolic version of this expression:

```
teSym = cb2Sym Cos[β]^2 + cs2Sym Sin[β]^2 + cscbSym Sin[β] Cos[β] + cPrimeSym
```

Use double angle formulas:

```
tmp = 
  Expand[teSym /. {Sin[β] Cos[β] -> TrigReduce[Sin[β] Cos[β]], 
                   Sin[β]^2 -> TrigReduce[Sin[β]^2], 
                   Cos[β]^2 -> TrigReduce[Cos[β]^2]}
  ]
```

Pull out the coefficients you want:

```
bPrimeSym =   Coefficient[tmp, Cos[2 β]]
aPrimeSym =   Coefficient[tmp, Sin[2 β]]
cPrimeSym = Select[tmp, FreeQ[#, β] &]
```

If you want to find the explicit form:

```
aPrime = aPrimeSym /. {cb2Sym -> cb2, cs2Sym -> cs2, cscbSym -> cscb}
bPrime = bPrimeSym /. {cb2Sym -> cb2, cs2Sym -> cs2, cscbSym -> cscb}
cPrime = cPrimeSym /. {cb2Sym -> cb2, cs2Sym -> cs2, cscbSym -> cscb}
```

Comment: And, Bob Hanlon's advice is the first step.